# (UK) Why did Colin Furze's Hoverbike not require a licence?

Tags: helicopter, pilot-certification, experimental-aircraft, uk

Link:

Why did he not need a licence to fly this?

Comment: Who says he didn't?

Comment: Maybe because they consider it a ground effect vehicle and nobody in their right mind would ever take it out of ground effect.

Comment: @WPNSGuy He hasn't mentioned any sort of licence in any of his videos at all

Comment: @JohnK Colin Furze lives in the UK. According to [this article](https://www.revolution.aero/editorial-1/2019/8/29/exclusive-uk-at-odds-with-eu-and-us-over-classification-of-wing-in-ground-effect-craft), the UK considers ground-effect vehicles to be airplanes.

Comment: Colin's been in legal trouble with a number of his builds -- what makes you think he didn't get some hassle from this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I recall from the video (I only watched it once, when it first dropped), one of the challenges of this build was making the machine light enough to meet UK/EU requirements for a no-license ultralight -- the rectangle-tube aluminum frame, minimal seat and handlebars all went toward this goal.

Bottom line is, he's below the UK weight limit, below the maximum speed permitted, and has less than the maximum fuel capacity allowed, so it's legally a no-license ultralight under UK/EU regulations.

Also, this build was sponsored by a major car manufacturer (Ford Motor Company, as I recall), who might well have helped with legal research as well as funding.

Comment: I would add that this contraption,  with all due respect, is pretty much certainly unable to operate outside ground effect. This may also free it from regulation. It is essentially a hovercraft of less than 1000kg mass, and as such not subject to registration in the UK.

Comment: FWIW, my recollection from the video is that this would also qualify as an ultralight in the US under Part 103 -- but might need to be registered *as a boat* like other hovercraft usually are.

Comment: It could if the HP was high enough.  You just wouldn't want to get it high enough that the highly probable 2 stroke engine failure  turns you into a falling object.